# MySQL - Populate a field based on part of another field

Tags: mysql, search, text

I have a table where one column, named Description, has a variety of information all crammed together. Part of that information is an abbreviation for a vehicle maker.  For example, the Description column could read `"6cylM.Benz32zy,.026L"`

I want to populate a new Vehicle column with Mercedes Benz wherever the `Description` column contains M.Benz somewhere inside. The key word there is "somewhere"; the abbreviated vehicle name could be anywhere in the description field.

So far I have the following code. However, MySQL tells me it can't find the %M.Benz% column. I'm not trying to look for a column named %M.Benz%, I'm trying to find TEXT that is %M.Benz%.

```
UPDATE tbl_arcore_repuestos
   SET Vehicle = `Mercedes Benz` 
 WHERE Description LIKE `%M.Benz%`;
```

Any ideas?  Most of the other solutions on StackOverflow to similar questions rely on the sought-after text being in a fixed position (like at the beginning of the string or separated by a consistent character). The text I'm looking for could be ANYWHERE in the `Description` column.

Answer (score 2):

Have you missed the quotes or used backticks instead of quotes?

```
UPDATE tbl_arcore_repuestos SET Vehicle = 'Mercedes Benz' WHERE Description LIKE '%M.Benz%';
```

Comment: I think he used backticks which in SO makes `Merceds Benz` instead of 'Mercedes Benz'

Comment: I am using backticks. I thought that was the preferred character for quoting text in MySQL. No? Should i use regular single/double quotes instead?

Comment: @user1687658 You should use regular quotes instead. backticks is used to quote the column/table names which has special chars or mysql reserve word.

Comment: That worked.  I didn't realize mysql made a distinction between backticks and quotes.  Thanks for the help and thanks for the education, too!